# Where in China is this recreation of Paris and the Eiffel tower (as seen in Jamie xx's Gosh video) and what is it like today?

Tags: china, paris, identify-this

The October 4, 2016 music video [*Gosh*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTGJfRPLe08) by [Jamie xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jamie_xx) was shot in a recreation of recognizable Paris buildings and sights, including a *very large* model of the Eiffel Tower. Scenes in the video show that at that time several components were still under construction.

Where exactly is this, and what does it look like today? Are there people living in all these buildings, walking the streets, perhaps riding an elevator to the top of the tower?

Related video: [Jamie xx - Gosh (Behind the Scenes)](https://youtu.be/R6CH18yyQyE)

---

[image: screenshot from the October 4, 2016 Jamie xx music video "Gosh" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTGJfRPLe08]

[image: screenshot from the October 4, 2016 Jamie xx music video "Gosh" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hTGJfRPLe08]

Comment: https://www.dailystar.co.uk/travel/travel-news/inside-chinese-city-built-fake-28066117

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this Billboard article](https://www.billboard.com/music/music-news/jamie-xx-gosh-video-behind-the-scenes-7533329/#!) it's Tianducheng near Hangzhou. This [travelogue article](https://www.nomadasaurus.com/tianducheng-chinas-strange-city-paris/), last updated in 2021, isn't very positive, making it sound like there is still a lot of construction and it's still largely unpopulated, but maybe someone who has been in person can report differently.